# как из постраничного апи выкачать все страницы?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http

есть **API** `https://api.com/users`
там не получит все итемы сразу можно только так
`https://api.com/users?pages=1` 1 это страница
но мне нужно все страницы

```
let page = 1
while(true) {
  fetch(`https://api.com/users?pages=${page++}`)
}
```

как их получить не используя циклы и быстро, с учетом что я не могу обращаться к **API** слишком часто ?

Comment: "получить не используя циклы" --- использовать setTimeout/setInterval

Comment: у клиента [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) есть [Pagination API](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/HEAD/documentation/4-pagination.md)